# redis client list shows lots of cmd=auth

Tags: redis, lettuce

Several modules in my environment suddenly unable to connect to Redis today, the error message says either unable make connection to Redis or Reconnecting, last destination was xxx. I see lots of clients with cmd=auth when I check with "client list". The total number of client goes to 600+, there is usually only less than 100. Is there any particular reason may cause such phenomenon?

Some clients use Lettuce, and some use Jedis for connection management.

The earliest error shows: "Cannot retrieve initial cluster partitions from initial URIs"

Answer (score 0):

> I see lots of clients with cmd=auth when I check with "client list"

It means that lots of clients are sending `AUTH` command to Redis.

It seems that someone is doing a brute-force attack to guess your password.